# Check last string if matched to first string (2 forms) - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two forms, form1 and form2. In form1 I have a textbox. User will input 2 letters and the last letter should match the first letter of the textbox input in form2 and will prompt an error if input letter is not the matched with the last letter from form1.

Is there a way to do this? Please help

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question you asked yesterday?  The other question had more detail and is probably more likely to get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed ways to do this.
You basically take the string from each texbox and compare them.

Simplest approach is to just put a check in the textbox for form2:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
If Not Left(Me.TextBox1.Value, 1) = Right(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value, 1) Then
    MsgBox "Not matching error text"
End If
End Sub
```

With adjustments for name changes of textboxes and userforms.

Using the [Left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function) and [Right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/right-function) functions to specify what part of the string we want to look at.

The value of textboxes in userforms are not saved if the form is closed. So the forms have to be non-modal and open at the same time. Otherwise you'd have save the value in some other way.